# How to check for navigation bar using a Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was trying to check two things in this below image:

[image]

1.The navigation bar is being displayed on the page with correct dimensions.

2.The texts "Home", "About Us" etc. are being displayed on the navigation bar correctly and are web links ( means they are working fine and are not broken).

To check if all the links are working fine, I have coded this, but I'm not sure if this is correct-

```
 List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

String[] linkTexts = new String[linkElements.size()];

int i = 0;

// extract the link texts of each link element

for (WebElement e : linkElements) {

    logger.info(linkTexts[i] = e.getText());

    i++;

}
for (String l : linkTexts) {

    driver.findElement(By.linkText(l)).click();

    if (driver.getTitle().equals(title)) {

        System.out.println("\"" + l + "\""

        + " is not Working.");

    } else {

        System.out.println("\"" + l + "\""

        + " is working.");

    }

    driver.navigate().back();

}
}
```

Comment: "but I'm not sure if this is correct" -- does this work?

Comment: Sadly no. I haven't tried the answer provided by HemaSundar though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use 'getCssValue' method get get the dimensions of the menu bar.

```
Eg:
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='panelGridInputCol']")).getCssValue("CSSAtribute");
```

2)
(a) To check whether the "HOME" and "About us" are displayed correctly on the navigation bar, again you can use 'getCssValue' method.
(b)

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement w : allLinks)
    {

        w.click();
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("Element on the page")).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is working");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is not working");
        }
        driver.navigate().back();//To come back to the Home screen

    }
```

Comment: Thanks HemaSundar. One question- For the first question, I will be able to get the CSS attribute that you've mentioned, but how will I check if that is displayed correctly. Using IsDisplayed() perhaps?

Comment: @geeko_zac I didn't understood what "correctly" means? You asked about "dimensions". so you check for "height", "padding" & "margin" .... like that based on your application's requirement.

Comment: I tried the program you have mentioned, but I am not able to check the links. first the 
`List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); ` line gave me an error, so I had to type cast it like this 
`List<WebElement> allLinks=(List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));`
However on running the program I got a ClassCastException.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List`
Please help.

Comment: it should be "findElements", not "findElement"

Comment: Yeah I realized this barely 2 minutes after posting this. :D
This program checks for all the links that are present in the page though. Is there a way I can limit it just to check the links that are present in the navigation bar.

Comment: @geeko_zac Yeah, U can. For u need to find the element the will cover complete Navigation bar. U can do it using FireBug.
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.XPATH("Coplete_navigationbar_xpath"));
List<WebElement> allLinks = menu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
These steps will give you links only in the Navigation bar.

Comment: I wrote the code like this 

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.XPATH("Coplete_navigationbar_xpath"));
 
   List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement w : allLinks)
    {

        w.click();
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("Element on the page")).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is working");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Link:"+w.getText()+"is not working");
        }
        driver.navigate().back();//To come back to the Home screen

    }

Comment: For the code in above comment, I am getting the links on the navigation bar displayed 39, which is the no of links present in navigation bar , including the sub menus. That's because we're  using tagname to initialize the loop count. I tried this using class name, but the program went into infinte loop. How I can print links only once. What element should be used to initialize the loop?

Comment: `WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.XPATH("Coplete_navigationbar_xpath")); List<WebElement> allLinks = menu.findElements(By.tagName("a"));`

Comment: While getting all the links use `menu.`, not `driver.`

Comment: Get the same output even if I get menu instead of driver.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using the id of unordered list inside the navigation panel. I initialized my list as
`code` List<WebElement> allLinks1=menu.findElements(By.id("menu-primary"));

Answer (score 0):

```
const selector = { className: 'navbar-nav'}

const navbar = () => driver.findElement(selector);

expect(await navbar().getText()).toContain('Home');
expect(await navbar().getText()).toContain('About Us');
```